# Overriding @JsonDeserialize and @JsonSerialize Behaviour

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a Spring(4.1.6) MVC project, properties annotated with @JsonDeserialize and @JsonSerialize in class Foo are working fine. Foo is used within a RestController hence managed by Rest calls.

Foo is packed within a common module hence need to be reused in other modules.

```
Something like:
-Web
--Common
-Services
--Common(Common is used in both)
```

we will be using ObjectMapper for conversion in Services module.But some how we need to override behavior so that @JsonDeserialize and @JsonSerialize are ignored in Services module and we get values as is.

One option I can think of is creating new bean extends Foo and overriding annotated properties.

Any pointers to other simple way of doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution within Mixin provided by jackson.
We can override Annotations using mixin as shown below for Deserialization(Serialization would be similar):

Step 1. Create a DummyDateDeSerializer, where we can write custom logic for date parsing.In my case I returned date as received.

Step 2. Create a Mixin Class defining properties for which anootations should be overriden.

> ```
> public abstract class DateMixin {
>   @JsonDeserialize(using=com.test.jackson.DummyDateDeSerializer.class)
>   public abstract Date getLastModifiedDate() ;
>   @JsonDeserialize(using=com.test.jackson.DummyDateDeSerializer.class)
>   public abstract Date getCreatedDate() ;
> }
> ```

Step 3.Create a DummyDateModule

> ```
> public class DummyDateModule extends SimpleModule {
>   public DummyDateModule() {
>       super("DummyDateModule", new Version(0, 0, 1, null));
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
>       context.setMixInAnnotations(Foo.class, DateMixin.class);
>   }
> }
> ```

Step 4. Register mdoule

> ```
>   private static void updateMapper(ObjectMapper mapper){
>       mapper.registerModule(new DummyDateModule());
>   }
> ```

This will override any @JsonDeserialize defined in Foo or its super class(es) with DummyDateDesrializer for properties createdDate and lastModifiedDate.